# Google Sheets: Index Match return multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Currently, I have an Index Match function that returns a single cell. I would like to return a specified number of cells in a row as shown in the attached image beside "Desired Return".

I would like to do this without implementing multiple index match functions such as:

```
={index(A1:E5,(match(G1,A1:A5,0)),2), index(A1:E5,(match(G1,A1:A5,0)),3), index(A1:E5,(match(G1,A1:A5,0)),4)}
```

and would like to implement a range of cells if possible as depicted below.

```
=index(A1:E5,(match(G1,A1:A5,0)),(2:4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the number of return cols, specify the appropriate range in `INDEX` function's first argument:

```
=index(B1:D6,(match(H1,A1:A6,0)),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(G1, A1:E, {2,3,4}, )))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but this still only returns the first cell in the specified range/array

Comment: @J.Cannor fixed, try now